# Azure functions all working but POST request

Tags: typescript, azure, rest, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I created an Azure functions application and created 4 functions in it. I read the documentation and used the exact given technique to connect with my SQL server database which is also hosted on Azure.

The 4 functions are for CRUD operations. Now my error is quite weird.

When I run application like after an hour and first send the POST request through POSTMAN, it works fine but then I send PATCH request to make changes in my database but the function sends 500 error.

Take the same case, now when I run application after an hour and run PATCH request first and then POST, PATCH works fine but POST starts sending 500 error.

I don't understand why am I getting this issue. It is also worth noting that when I run each of these functions (POST and PATCH) individually from the Azure console they provide to test functions, they both work fine there. I don't understand this behaviour.

My code is exactly like the documentation so I am certain that my code is not misbehaving. What I am assuming is that maybe there is some issue with SQL Server connection pooling but I am not certain about it. I looked into SQL Server resources and they are barely touched so my resources are also not exhausted.

*POST FUNCTION:*

```js
import {
    app,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponseInit,
    InvocationContext,
    output,
} from "@azure/functions";

const sql = output.sql({
    commandText: "Employees",
    connectionStringSetting: "SqlConnectionString",
});

export async function addEmployee(
    request: HttpRequest,
    context: InvocationContext
): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    try {
        const body = await request.json();
        context.extraOutputs.set(sql, body);

        return {
            jsonBody: { message: `Successfully added new Employee Record` },
        };
    } catch (e: Error | any) {
        return { jsonBody: e.message };
    }
}

app.http("addEmployee", {
    methods: ["POST"],
    authLevel: "anonymous",
    extraOutputs: [sql],
    handler: addEmployee,
    route: "employees/add",
});
```

*PATCH FUNCTION*

```js
import {
    app,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponseInit,
    InvocationContext,
    output,
} from "@azure/functions";

const sql = output.sql({
    commandText: "Employees",
    connectionStringSetting: "SqlConnectionString",
});

export async function editEmployee(
    request: HttpRequest,
    context: InvocationContext
): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    try {
        const body = await request.json();
        context.extraOutputs.set(sql, body);

        return {
            jsonBody: { message: `Successfully edited new Employee Record` },
        };
    } catch (e: Error | any) {
        return { jsonBody: e.message };
    }
}

app.http("editEmployee", {
    methods: ["PATCH"],
    authLevel: "anonymous",
    extraOutputs: [sql],
    handler: editEmployee,
    route: "employees/edit",
});
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I have added code in the original description @LajosArpad

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the errors that you encounter when you get the status of 500?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to azure and learning it, I don't know where I can get those

Comment: You should be able to find them in the server logs. Maybe this link helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/94289/how-to-view-the-application-logs-of-an-azure-web-a

Comment: I found them and it says --> Failed Method: Microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.onerror

there was no more detail given in that section about the error within the logs

however, again it works fine when I run PATCH first before POST with a delay of 1 hour.

Comment: Okay, so it's a connection error. Do you have a stack trace of the issue?

Comment: I found the problem, turns out that in my POST request, I was sending only name and age as the id that was primary key was to be auto generated. However it was causing problems and mismatching the columns when I sent only name and age. 

I simply provided id as 1 and now it works absolutely fine. Perhaps the azure functions library should look into the fact when tables ids are auto generated, it should  not look for id from clients